# R impulse response function: expected values lie outside of the confidence interval

Tags: r

It is common sense that expected values should lie inside the confidence intervals. What I got from R impulse response function is that the expected values are very close to the thresholds of the 95% confidence interval or even outside of it as you may see in the following image: [image: R impulse response function plot]

How could it be explainable?

These are the commands that I used to model IRF:

```
VARs_F2 <- VAR(FAVAR_F2, p=10, type="both")
IRF_F2 <- irf(VARs_F2, impulse="F2",
              response=c("GDP_Growth","deleyed_payments","inflation"), n.ahead=16)
plot(IRF_F2)
```

I tried that with different datasets.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the impulse response function, so there might well be something funky going on with that, I can't tell. But it's also true that common sense is misleading on this one: a confidence interval need not contain the expected value. As an extreme example: you get a perfectly valid 50% confidence interval by the procedure of guessing [-inf,inf] half the time and 0 half the time. The interval obeys the normal properties of a confidence interval, but won't necessarily contain the expected value. It's super counterintuitive, but more realistic confidence intervals are subject to the same thing for the same basic reason. More details here: https://richarddmorey.shinyapps.io/confidenceFallacy/ paper is linked from the 'story' tab.

I don't know if that's actually the reason for the result you're describing here... but it might be worth checking the possibility?